# Why Tensorflow not running on GPU while GPU devices are identified in python?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, windows-10, tensorflow2.0

I installed `TensorFlow 2.2.0` and `TensorFlow-gpu 2.2.0` in `windows 10`. Also, I installed `CUDA Toolkit v10.1` and copy `cuDNN 7.6.5` files in `CUDA directories`. My GPU is `NVIDIA GeForce 940 MX`.
In addition, I set CUDA Path on windows. When I test devices through the below code, both `CPU` and `GPU` are recognized:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

The output is:

```
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
 device_type: "CPU"
 memory_limit: 268435456
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 13265748925766868529,
 name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
 device_type: "XLA_CPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 14569071601529958377
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device",
 name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
 device_type: "XLA_GPU"
 memory_limit: 17179869184
 locality {
 }
 incarnation: 15045400394346252324
 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"]
```

But, when I run my code, it seems the codes are run just on CPU. In addition, when I test GPU availability with `tf.test.is_gpu_available()`, GPU devices cannot be recognized and `False value` is shown.
Or when we run `tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`, an `empty list` or `[]` is printed. And when I run `tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices()`, these three `physical devices` are shown in a list:

```
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'),
 PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_CPU:0', device_type='XLA_CPU'),
 PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_GPU:0', device_type='XLA_GPU')]
```

It is important that when I run `tf.config.list_physical_devices('XLA_GPU')`, this will be printed:
`[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_GPU:0', device_type='XLA_GPU')]`

Also, when we run the code, task manager show that **CPU use 96% of its capability and GPU use only 1% of its capability.**

The code we run is as follow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout, Bidirectional
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, TensorBoard
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from yahoo_fin import stock_info as si
from collections import deque

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import os
import random


# set seed, so we can get the same results after rerunning several times
np.random.seed(314)
tf.random.set_seed(314)
random.seed(314)


def load_data(ticker, n_steps=50, scale=True, shuffle=True, lookup_step=1, 
                test_size=0.2, feature_columns=['adjclose', 'volume', 'open', 'high', 'low']):
    # see if ticker is already a loaded stock from yahoo finance
    if isinstance(ticker, str):
        # load it from yahoo_fin library
        df = si.get_data(ticker)
    elif isinstance(ticker, pd.DataFrame):
        # already loaded, use it directly
        df = ticker
    # this will contain all the elements we want to return from this function
    result = {}
    # we will also return the original dataframe itself
    result['df'] = df.copy()
    # make sure that the passed feature_columns exist in the dataframe
    for col in feature_columns:
        assert col in df.columns, f"'{col}' does not exist in the dataframe."
    if scale:
        column_scaler = {}
        # scale the data (prices) from 0 to 1
        for column in feature_columns:
            scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
            df[column] = scaler.fit_transform(np.expand_dims(df[column].values, axis=1))
            column_scaler[column] = scaler

        # add the MinMaxScaler instances to the result returned
        result["column_scaler"] = column_scaler
    # add the target column (label) by shifting by `lookup_step`
    df['future'] = df['adjclose'].shift(-lookup_step)
    # last `lookup_step` columns contains NaN in future column
    # get them before droping NaNs
    last_sequence = np.array(df[feature_columns].tail(lookup_step))
    # drop NaNs
    df.dropna(inplace=True)
    sequence_data = []
    sequences = deque(maxlen=n_steps)
    for entry, target in zip(df[feature_columns].values, df['future'].values):
        sequences.append(entry)
        if len(sequences) == n_steps:
            sequence_data.append([np.array(sequences), target])
    # get the last sequence by appending the last `n_step` sequence with `lookup_step` sequence
    # for instance, if n_steps=50 and lookup_step=10, last_sequence should be of 59 (that is 50+10-1) length
    # this last_sequence will be used to predict in future dates that are not available in the dataset
    last_sequence = list(sequences) + list(last_sequence)
    # shift the last sequence by -1
    last_sequence = np.array(pd.DataFrame(last_sequence).shift(-1).dropna())
    # add to result
    result['last_sequence'] = last_sequence
    # construct the X's and y's
    X, y = [], []
    for seq, target in sequence_data:
        X.append(seq)
        y.append(target)
    # convert to numpy arrays
    X = np.array(X)
    y = np.array(y)
    # reshape X to fit the neural network
    X = X.reshape((X.shape[0], X.shape[2], X.shape[1]))
    # split the dataset
    result["X_train"], result["X_test"], result["y_train"], result["y_test"] = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=test_size, shuffle=shuffle)
    # return the result
    return result


def create_model(sequence_length, units=256, cell=LSTM, n_layers=2, dropout=0.3,
                loss="mean_absolute_error", optimizer="rmsprop", bidirectional=False):
    model = Sequential()
    for i in range(n_layers):
        if i == 0:
            # first layer
            if bidirectional:
                model.add(Bidirectional(cell(units, return_sequences=True), input_shape=(None, sequence_length)))
            else:
                model.add(cell(units, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(None, sequence_length)))
        elif i == n_layers - 1:
            # last layer
            if bidirectional:
                model.add(Bidirectional(cell(units, return_sequences=False)))
            else:
                model.add(cell(units, return_sequences=False))
        else:
            # hidden layers
            if bidirectional:
                model.add(Bidirectional(cell(units, return_sequences=True)))
            else:
                model.add(cell(units, return_sequences=True))
        # add dropout after each layer
        model.add(Dropout(dropout))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation="linear"))
    model.compile(loss=loss, metrics=["mean_absolute_error"], optimizer=optimizer)
    return model

# Window size or the sequence length
N_STEPS = 100
# Lookup step, 1 is the next day
LOOKUP_STEP = 1
# test ratio size, 0.2 is 20%
TEST_SIZE = 0.2
# features to use
FEATURE_COLUMNS = ["adjclose", "volume", "open", "high", "low"]
# date now
date_now = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
### model parameters
N_LAYERS = 3
# LSTM cell
CELL = LSTM
# 256 LSTM neurons
UNITS = 256
# 40% dropout
DROPOUT = 0.4
# whether to use bidirectional RNNs
BIDIRECTIONAL = False
### training parameters
# mean absolute error loss
# LOSS = "mae"
# huber loss
LOSS = "huber_loss"
OPTIMIZER = "adam"
BATCH_SIZE = 64
EPOCHS = 400
# Apple stock market
ticker = "AAPL"
ticker_data_filename = os.path.join("data", f"{ticker}_{date_now}.csv")
# model name to save, making it as unique as possible based on parameters
model_name = f"{date_now}_{ticker}-{LOSS}-{OPTIMIZER}-{CELL.__name__}-seq-{N_STEPS}-step-{LOOKUP_STEP}-layers-{N_LAYERS}-units-{UNITS}"
if BIDIRECTIONAL:
    model_name += "-b"
    
# create these folders if they does not exist
if not os.path.isdir("results"):
    os.mkdir("results")
if not os.path.isdir("logs"):
    os.mkdir("logs")
if not os.path.isdir("data"):
    os.mkdir("data")


# load the data
data = load_data(ticker, N_STEPS, lookup_step=LOOKUP_STEP, test_size=TEST_SIZE, feature_columns=FEATURE_COLUMNS)

# save the dataframe
data["df"].to_csv(ticker_data_filename)

# construct the model
model = create_model(N_STEPS, loss=LOSS, units=UNITS, cell=CELL, n_layers=N_LAYERS,
                    dropout=DROPOUT, optimizer=OPTIMIZER, bidirectional=BIDIRECTIONAL)

# some tensorflow callbacks
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join("results", model_name + ".h5"), save_weights_only=True, save_best_only=True, verbose=1)
tensorboard = TensorBoard(log_dir=os.path.join("logs", model_name))

history = model.fit(data["X_train"], data["y_train"],
                    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                    epochs=EPOCHS,
                    validation_data=(data["X_test"], data["y_test"]),
                    callbacks=[checkpointer, tensorboard],
                    verbose=1)

model.save(os.path.join("results", model_name) + ".h5")
```

`**GPU and CPU performance**` are as follow:

[image]

Could you help me, please?

Comment: I have both CPU 1.14 and GPU 2.1, so in 1.14 I have no GPU devices available via ```device_lib.list_local_devices()``` and ```tf.test.is_gpu_available()``` gives False. Contrary, in 2.1 I see my GPU device and ```tf.test.is_gpu_available()``` gives True. 

I think there are only two solutions here: 1) Something installed wrong,  2) Bug in tensorflow library for current version, so try to install 2.1 for example. 

Also, try to write issue on tensorflow girhub explaining your way of installation etc.

Comment: When you import tensorflow, a big log is shown in the terminal or output device, please include it in your question, it will tell you if CUDA libs have been found and if not what versions are required.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but before I installed TensorFlow 1 and it was working well on GPU.

Comment: @IvanShelonik I test TensorFlow 2.1, but it cannot be worked, too.

Comment: When I run tf.test.is_built_with_cuda(), it returns True value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem with set `NVIDIA Control Panel`. I press right click on desktop and choose `NVIDIA Control panel`:
[image: NVIDIA Control Panel]

---

Then, Through `Set PhysX Configuration`, I go to `Select a PhysX  Processor` and select `Auto-Select recommended` like this:
[image: Auto-Select recommended]

---

Also, from `Manage 3D settings`, I restored the settings by clicking on `Restore button`:
[image: Restore]
Also, you can set Python on GPU from `Program Settings` of this section. I did that.Please, apply all changes in every stage.
Finally, with run each of above codes favorable results were shown like this:

---

```
Code1:
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
device_lib.list_local_devices()
Output1:
[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 12330560057435677891
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 14076398930644318194
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 3186897715
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 5889399188264267952
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce 940MX, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 5.0"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 8080361800351872259
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]
```

---

```
Code2:
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')

Output2:
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

---

```
Code3:
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
Output3:
True
```

---

Comment: Thank you. Your solution was very helpful. I mean the error message were pushing along another path, namely installing alternative versions/additional programs of NVIDIA GPU framework.

Answer (score -2):

The code should be like this:

```
def load_data(ticker, n_steps=N_STEPS)
```

so you can pass the variable you defined as 100 ahead in the code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Note that Stack Overflow's Q/A format isn't intended for forum-style discussions. Do not ask your own question by giving an "answer" to someone else's question! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works. If you have a question, then create your own question, reference this question if it's related, and explain in detail your problem. Before posting your own question, please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and see also [the question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/5698098).

Comment: Your answer is very irrelevant.